# How can I upload files to Windows 10 from Samsung Galaxy S5?

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, android, usb-storage, smartphone

I installed **Android USB Driver** on my Windows 10 laptop as well as **Samsung Smart Switch** on both

**a)** Windows 10 laptop 
**b)** Samsung Galaxy S5

I tried to connect Windows laptop with Samsung phone via **Samsung Smart Switch** but it is not working. I used an USB cable for the connection.

Comment: Windows 10 supports MTP natively, can't you just connect it and then grab the pull down notification window and change the USB mode to MTP?

Comment: Check what type of USB cable you're using. Some USB cables can only carry charge, not data. For example any discount shop USB cable probably won't carry data.

Answer (score 0):

I changed an USB cable and now it is working!!!